# Geometric Interpretation of Whether SVMs are performing well or not

Tags: machine-learning, svm, kernel-trick, nonlinear, model-evaluation

I came across this [research paper](http://media.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/~taopin/ML2005/intro2Kernel-basedLearn-TNN-2001.pdf) which contained this figure [image]

which talks about the center of mass (presumably, of the training dataset's datapoints?) and represents the solution of an SVM as polygon (or is it a point?).
I'm having trouble understanding this figure, and since it seems to provide a geometric interpretation of when an SVM performs poorly or not, I'm interested in it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different regions to observe in each figure: $P$ which is the "pseudo polygon" where the dots don't appear. Let us refer to the area of the "pseudo polygon" as $A_P$ from here on.

The aim of the author here is to estimate this "pseudo polygon". In both figures, it is estimated with an ellipsis $E$. Call its area $A_E$.

In the first figure, you can see that $A_P$ and $A_E$ are close to each other, and geometrically "resemble" to each other.

On the other hand, on the second figure, there is still a lot of room between the ellipsis and the pseudo polygon, which means that you have a poor estimation of the region $A$.

*Edit.* Calling $\tilde{f}$ the classifier obtained with the SVM, the "pseudo polygon" is defined implicitly from $\{x|\tilde{f}(x)=1\}$.

Comment: But how do you get the pseudo-polygon's from SVMs. I know how we can get the hyperplane, but how do we go from there to the geometric objects in the figure?

Comment: @Ragnar I just added the information in the answer!

Comment: So $\tilde{f}$ is the hyperplane right. Then why do you construct the set $\{x \mid \tilde{f}(x) = 1\}$. Is that the set of support vectors? Lastly, assuming the $x$'s are datapoints, how are they plotted and on what space are they plotted? I don't see any familiar axes in the figure. Thanks again!